# How to select a row from ajax table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, row

I have a bit of experience with PHP and mysql, but am just getting into Javascript/ajax and I am stuck in working with ajax.

I have a page that I in this page there is a live (ajax) search that shows the user rows of database. 
The problem is when I search for a user in live search there are more than one rows about that user and I want to edit one of them each time I mean I want to select a row from ajax table with a checkbox on the left of the table, in the ajax code I want to select that row that I marked in the edit page and return the value of that row to the edit page for editing. 
I don't know how to select that row that its checkbox was marked.

These two link in the below are pages code :

editing page : https://www.dropbox.com/s/82dj5921xbs14c2/editstudent.php

ajax page : https://www.dropbox.com/s/fg4dsh9c7mepov6/ssearch.php

The ajax page is just for connecting to database and showing information and returning a value.

Comment: Please post the most relevant bits of code here, not just as links.

Comment: It's a bit unclear, what you want achieve. But you can get the `tr` with checked checkbox by adding all the checkboxes some class and this code `var tr=$('input.someCalss:checked').closest('tr')` But multiple checkboxes can be checket so you can get more than one `tr` so I would sugges using `radios` instead. But obviouslz you want to send the checked row to server to edit the DB. If you want to do this by ajax, you have to use javascript & php webservice concept. So give us some better info or google it.

Comment: this links are the codes , because there are lots of line I couldn't have put them in here.

Comment: @david can I select one row with radio box ? if it's possible how can I do that ?

Comment: Nope, but radios prevent the user from selecting more than one row. Just replace the `input type="checkbox"`  by `input type="radio"` But still I don't know what are you trying to do. Maybe try to edit your post and simply write what do you want the user to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the tr row like that

```
      var tr = $('#checkboxID').parent().parent();
```

and if your tr have id then

```
   var tr = $('#checkboxID').parent().parent().attr("id") ;
```

Comment: what about radiobox ? if I use this code can I send this variable or this row to editing page ?

Comment: its the same for radiobox if its in an input inside a td. and you can send it to edit page yes.

Comment: thanks but the code you've written up above is not working , is it for php ?

Comment: no , you dont see its jquery? , show your code and then i can see why its not working.

Comment: oh I haven't worked with jquery yet ! could you give me and example code or template about it ? my code is up above i've uploaded a piece of ajax page on dropbox .

Comment: as I said above, in editing page there is a live search input box that I want to write a usernumber in it and it shows me more than one user from database , then I want to select one of them I mean mark one of them and press enter then this row will appear in editing page table . in ajax code page I have to put a code for marking this row .